# How can one set the math mode font of a document to be the italics mode of the document font family

Tags: math-mode, fonts

I'm using the [Baskervaldaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob0Wv.png) as the default font family in my document. I would prefer to use the italics of this font family as the default math mode text for equations and inline maths, i.e. the font accessed by using `\textit{x y z a b c}` for example.

Does anyone know how I can set the math mode font to be the default italics mode of the Baskervaldaf font package?

---

Specifically I want the result where using, `$ a b c x y z$`, or `\begin{equation}` gives the font style

[image]

Comment: You can try [mathastext](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathastext), cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506496/29873

Comment: @DG' That did it. I'll add an answer for other users but credit you for the point in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that an adequate answer to your question? I hope to have understood your request. Here's a little code with the image. See also my previous request [mtpro2 + baskerville in math](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419976/mtpro2-baskerville-in-math?rq=1).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[Baskervaldx]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\itshape\lipsum[5]
\[ f(x)=e^{\sin x} \]
\itshape\lipsum[2]
{\itshape my text}
\end{document}
```

Comment: EVEN BETTER!!!!!

Comment: @Q.P. I'm very happy to help you and the users :-)